# Android SMS not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sms

Below is my code for sending a SMS message. My phone number is 614xxxxxxx. I try typing +1614xxxxxxx or 1614xxxxxxx or 614xxxxxxx for the number and some text for the message. No error shows up but my phone cannot get the message?

```
 protected void sendMessage(){
        String number=no.getText().toString();
        String message=msg.getText().toString();

        SmsManager manager=SmsManager.getDefault();
        manager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);

}
```

Comment: How long is your message? If it exceeds the character limit for the alphabet you're using, you'll need to use the `sendMultipartTextMessage()` method instead .

Comment: I type "aaa" @MikeM.

Comment: Which `SmsManager` class do you have imported? It should be `android.telephony.SmsManager`.

Comment: @MikeM. I import this.

Comment: Well, then I would recommend that you include a sent `PendingIntent` for the fourth argument in your `sendTextMessage()` call, setup a `BroadcastReceiver` for it, and check the error code there.

Comment: Can you give me the code? I do not have experience in broadcast receiver.

Comment: I know what the problem is.....I need to send it using phone rather than in the emulator......

Comment: Ah. Guess I shoulda asked that at the start. Just FYI, if you only have one device, you can have it send a text to itself to test. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The call you are making is right.
Did you add the SEND_SMS permission? This must be done on the manifest.
You can read a good tutorial here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_sms.htm

It also has an example